Can you test whether a function is actually running Asynchronously?
I'm working on a ASP.NET Web Api project to learn the framework and the testing for it and I was wondering if you could test that Asynchronous methods are actually running Asynchronously (or are they running Synchronously due to any errors for example).
    public class RepositoryBase<Tentity, Tcontext> : IRepositoryBase<Tentity> where Tentity : class where Tcontext : DbContext
    {
        protected Tcontext _RepositoryContext;
        protected DbSet<Tentity> dbSet;
        public RepositoryBase(Tcontext context)
        {
            this._RepositoryContext = context;
            dbSet = _RepositoryContext.Set<Tentity>();
        }
        public async Task Create(Tentity entity)
        {
            await dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
        }
    }

Can you Test whether the Create method is actually running asynchronously?
Is it logical to test whether a method is running asynchronously? Or is it a trivial concern because the fact that it's returning a Task is proof it is running asynchronously.
During unit testing, in my test function, I only tried await repository.Create(testUser); and then later Asserted that the user inside the database and the one I inputted are identical in all aspects. But that's just testing the end functionality of the Create function and not whether its successfully running asynchronously or not.
My aim is not to test or question this specific framework itself but to question if any generic async function could be tested for its asynchronous nature. The example code above is just the context under which this question appeared in my head.

No, no, and no, in order of the questions.

It sounds as if you don't trust the framework doing things async when you told the framework/runtime by coding accordingly that it should do it? Is testing the framework/runtime your intention?

You would test for the internals of your function. From a client-perspective it is is completely irrelevant if the function really does any async code at all. You should only care for what it returns, which is a task. No other promise is given by th API, and thus you shouldn't bother for others.

@Ralf return Task.FromResult(VerySynchronous());

@GSerg Then you told the runtime via code that it shouldn't be async. Does that need a test?

@Ralf The very premise of the question is that you are a consumer of the function that may do return Task.FromResult(VerySynchronous());, but you don't know that. How would you know that, and if there was a way to know, what is it that you would be looking for? None of this has anything to do with testing the correctness of the async implementation in the framework.

if you dont trust the framework in case of doing framework things you should consider writing your own. Its a skill issue of a programmer if his  "asynchronous code" works like synchronous one, and there is nearly no way of checking that to be 100% sure.

@GSerg I think the point is: a client of a function that returns Task should not expect it to execute asynchronously (always). And that's why testing if it does makes no sense.

@WhiteH From the consumer point of view all you should care about is that the function returns an awaitable (which Task is the most common example of). Beyond that, what you will quickly discover is that you actually need to define "running asynchronously" first to be able to test for it. Do you, for example, mean that the called function, at some point, enters the no thread phase? I have no idea how you would test for that.

@GSerg. He is talking about unittest. So presumably the dbset is mocked away and presumably does a Task.FromResult. So in his test it will be sync while in production it might be async.  I see your point but it isn't testable in the classic unit-test sense.

"My aim is [...] to question if any generic async function should/could be tested for its asynchronous nature." -- Should or could? These two are completely different questions. The original question (revision 1) was about the could. If you want to know about the should, I would suggest to ask a new question. FYI questions on StackOverflow are expected to be uni-dimensional. Questions that ask for more than one thing tend to be closed for the reason "too broad, lacks focus". A should question might be closed as opinion-based though.

That question makes not much sense IMHO. Imagine a sync function like this one:
int DoSomething(int i) { ... }

From a consumer-perspective all you know - and all you should test for - is what the function expects and what it returns in that case. You would never come to the assumption to check if the function really does anything with the parameter. Instead you just check its return-value.
Your async code is in no way different: it returns a Task, which pretends there's some async code running inside of it.
Task DoSomething() { ... }

When calling this function we just care for its externals, not its actual implementation. We have no way to check what it does internally. We can just assume that something async code is there. Even the async keyword tells us nothing. If the function was defined on an interface, async wouldn't even exist, so we couldn't rely on that either.
So afterall there's no point on testing if the function really calls into any async code, or if it just pretends to do; the same as in the first example if it really uses the parameter.

"which pretends there's some async code running inside of it" - actually only pretends to have the potential to running async code, right?

@fildor eeeeehm, well, when it is an asnyc function I'd argue a function to definitly have the potential of doing something async. No await without async. In a function without async however, yes, I see your point.

Exactly. If we think about an interface - async wouldn't be part of it. Just the Task return type. Any implementation could have it or not. -- Just a thought, not making any specific point ...


Can you test whether the Create method is actually running asynchronously?

Yes, but not with 100% confidence. You can test that the method returns a Task that has not completed yet. Instead of:
await repository.Create(testUser);

...do this:
Task task = repository.Create(testUser);
Debug.Assert(!task.IsCompleted);
await task;


If the task.IsCompleted is false, it means that the task will complete asynchronously in the future.
If the task.IsCompleted is true, it means that either completed synchronously, or that it completed asynchronously so fast that you didn't have the chance to observe it (extremely unlikely scenario).

